# UserFrosting + QT: Authentication similar to OpenID?

Tags: qt, authentication, openid, userfrosting

I am currently working on a project involving a Windows desktop client based on QT that needs to be connected to a server hosting an user management software (OpenID) for user authentication before further operations within the client.

I am tasked to use a different server and software (UserFrosting), and then replace relevant code in QT to get the client to connect to the new server and software. So far I have managed to get the server and software up, but I am unable to figure out how to get the client to connect to UserFrosting for authentication.

To be exact, I am unable to find similar pages such as this for UserFrosting:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#http_encoding

So, may I know if UserFrosting has a similar page like this that I have overlooked in the API, or am I understanding how UserFrosting does authentication wrongly?

Thanks!